# Wrapping synchronize with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have one use case that I need to save the data into a Map. I'm trying to use the concurrentMap
I need to update/extract the value of the record later so that I have to use a Map(Queue, List won't work because I can't extract the value when the collection it self is updated).

Now my question is: Since I need to check the size of the Map before executing, how could I do that? Do I have to wrap map with synchronized or try to lock it? Is there any other way I could do that?

Comment: As far as I understand, you're using concurrentHashMap and trying to check the size of concurrentHashMap in thread-safe way? If so, you don't need to worry. concurrentHashMap is fully thread-safe.

Comment: While I understand it is thread-safe. But say I have a size limit of 1. I check the size of the concurrentHashMap it is empty. But before I start inserting, another thread just come in and insert one value. So if my current thread insert, then the map will have two records.

Comment: I think you don't need to use concurrentHashMap. 
Instead, I recommand `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference`.
ex) `new AtomicReference<>(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry(key, value)).compareAndSet(null, something)`